# How to remove Axis2 web service

Tags: apache-axis

Is there a way to remove an already deployed axis2 web service ?

I tried deactivating, but that does not remove the web service, it merely disables it till the system is restarted.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the artifact from the services folder. you may have to set hot update true. Please see the axis2.xml.

Comment: I tried to remove the artifact from service folder but it is showing that it is used by JDK. What to do in this case?